# When I use Bloc pattern My infinite list doesn't scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I want to make infinite list with bloc pattern but My bloc builder works only 1 time.After scroll the page "yield" doesn't work so bloc builder doesn't build.The new items comes but state doesn't build.

deliveries_bloc.dart:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_asten_app/data/orders_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter_asten_app/models/order_list.dart';

import '../../locater.dart';

part 'deliveries_event.dart';
part 'deliveries_state.dart';

class DeliveriesBloc extends Bloc<DeliveriesEvent, DeliveriesState> {
  final OrdersRepository ordersRepository = getIt<OrdersRepository>();
  DeliveriesBloc() : super(DeliveriesInitial());
  List<OrderList> orderss = [];

  @override
  Stream<DeliveriesState> mapEventToState(
    DeliveriesEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is FetchDeliveriesEvent) {
      yield DeliveriesLoadingState();
      try {
        final orders = await ordersRepository.getOrderList(event.page);
        print(orders.length);
        yield DeliveriesLoadedState(orders: orders);
      } catch (_) {
        yield DeliveriesErrorState();
      }
    } else if (event is FetchMoreDeliveriesEvent) {
      try {
        final orders = await ordersRepository.getMoreOrderList(event.page);
        print(orders.length);                  //this is for check the orders length
        yield DeliveriesLoadedState(orders: orders);
      } catch (_) {
        yield DeliveriesErrorState();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see in the above when my event is FetchMoreDeliveriesEvent my orders lengths icreases but the yield DeliveriesLoadedState(orders: orders); doesn't work
deliveries_state.dart:

```
part of 'deliveries_bloc.dart';

abstract class DeliveriesState extends Equatable {
  const DeliveriesState();
}

class DeliveriesInitial extends DeliveriesState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class DeliveriesLoadingState extends DeliveriesState {
  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object> get props => throw UnimplementedError();
}

class DeliveriesLoadedState extends DeliveriesState {
  final List<OrderList> orders;

  DeliveriesLoadedState({@required this.orders});
  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object> get props => [orders];
}

class DeliveriesErrorState extends DeliveriesState {
  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object> get props => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

deliveries_event.dart:

```
part of 'deliveries_bloc.dart';

abstract class DeliveriesEvent extends Equatable {
  const DeliveriesEvent();
}

class FetchDeliveriesEvent extends DeliveriesEvent {
  final int page;
  FetchDeliveriesEvent({@required this.page});
  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object> get props => [page];
}

class FetchMoreDeliveriesEvent extends DeliveriesEvent {
  final int page;
  FetchMoreDeliveriesEvent({@required this.page});
  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object> get props => [page];
}
```

the part of Main_page

```
Expanded(
                      child: BlocBuilder<DeliveriesBloc, DeliveriesState>(
                        bloc: _ordersBloc,
                        builder: (context, DeliveriesState state) {
                          if (state is DeliveriesLoadingState) {
                            return Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            );
                          }
                          if (state is DeliveriesLoadedState) {
                            return ListView.builder(
                                controller: _scrollController,
                                itemCount: state.orders.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Card(
                                    elevation: 4,
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      title: Text(state.orders[index].firadi),
                                      subtitle: Text(state.orders[index].sidttr
                                          .toString()),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                });
                          } else {
                            return null;
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Insert your ListView.builder in ScrollBar widget. check -> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Bloc builder re-build the widgets only if its content changes. Make sure you are providing your change detectable variables to your equatable's props getter.

If your `OrderList` class is not extending from Equatable, the orders fields change won't be reflected in state.

Check if you extended your `OrderList` class with `Equatable`, if yes make sure you added its props as well.

Comment: first of all thank you for your help,
The size of the array which is "orders" is changing.Is this change isn't enough for the bloc sees the change?

Comment: If that's the case, that should be enough, but make sure this as well, as u should not face any issue with other business logic like just changing the content of an item in future.
Going in the other direction, try adding a unique key to your listTile or Card in the ListView builder function

Answer (score 1):

The key concept here is understanding how the framework detects changes in the state to trigger a rebuild at the Widget level. **If you change the items in the list that is not detected as a change since the only comparison the framework performs is checking if the reference to the list is the same.**

As a workaround, you can add a property to the state `int nonce`.

```
class DeliveriesLoadedState extends DeliveriesState {
  final List<OrderList> orders;
  final int nonce;

  DeliveriesLoadedState({@required this.orders, @required this.nonce});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [orders];
}
```

So every time you emit a new state that changes the list you also change the value of `nonce`. That would force the framework to detect the state change.

```
@override
  Stream<DeliveriesState> mapEventToState(
    DeliveriesEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is FetchDeliveriesEvent) {
      yield DeliveriesLoadingState();
      try {
        final orders = await ordersRepository.getOrderList(event.page);
        yield DeliveriesLoadedState(orders: orders, nonce: DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch);
      } catch (_) {
        yield DeliveriesErrorState();
      }
    ...
  }
```